# Is it possible to add Prism's ContainerExtension to a WCF service hosted in a windows service?

Tags: c#, wcf, prism

My situation is that I have a set of applications and shared services in both WPF and generic .Net Framework class libraries which all use Dependancy Injection, specifically Prism.Unity.

All of this works well and I am able to Register DI components via the IContainerExtension interface that gets passed in via the constructor of the shared service.

For example the constructor for the SharedPrinting Service looks like,

SharedPrintingService(IContainerExtension container)
{
_dependantService = container.Resolve();
... etc etc

}

The dependant services are all registered via the RegisterTypes override of the PrismApplication Base class that is used in all of the parent WPF Projects.

The issue I have now is I need to implement a WCF component that is hosted via a Windows service that does some "things" that will utilise some of the shared service (like SharedPrintingService for example).

I have tried wiring up a basic Unity Style DI for the WindowsService --> WCF and whilst that works inside the "MainService" that is spun app from the service host. If I try and then use SharedPrintingService from the MainService I get a "No public constructor is available for type Prism.Ioc.IContainerExtension." obviously becasue it is not being initalised from WCF.

I am happy to use the Prism IOC model for WCF as it is effecively unity anyway. However, how can I create the container and therefore extension if the entrypoint is a WCF service and there is no "Application" base to implement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WCF with Unity. Essentially, you create and add an `IContractBehavior` that changes the `InstanceProvider` to one that uses your container.

There's an implementation [at github (and nuget)](https://github.com/unitycontainer/wcf).

But registration of types does not work cross-process, of course, so you cannot have a service shared between a regular app and a service. Good news is, that the app can talk to the wcf interface to do whatever sharing of information you need.

Important side-note: `SharedPrintingService(IContainerExtension container) { _dependantService = container.Resolve(); }` is horrible style, there's usually no reason not to use `SharedPrintingService( IService injectedService )`.

Comment: Thanks. The issue isn't so much about "how to get DI to work with WCF" but how to get Prism's DI to work with WCF. Which I understand is unity however it doesn't play nice with the "container.Resolve" pattern that Prism encourages...

I agree with Injecting via the constructor but in some cases I have 10-15 dependancies that need to be resolved and it's 'cleaner' (IMO) to resolve them in the constructor. In reality I actually do a little of both which isn't prefect practice but is fine for most situations.

Comment: I dare to disagree, and you'll join me as soon as you write the first tests :-) I'll 100% of the time prefer a long-ish list of constructor parameters over mocking the container.

Comment: Yeah possibly, I can see the advantage in that regard.